# Error while setting up Instant Apps

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-instant-apps

I'm trying to implement Android Instant Apps Support to my app and I've followed this tutorial:

http://androidkt.com/instant-app/

Everything was going perfect and I've successfully completed the tutorial.

But, I faced this error:

> Error:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':appapk:preDebugBuild'. > Android dependency 'com.android.support:support-v4' has different
>     version for the compile (25.2.0) and runtime (27.0.1) classpath. You
>     should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 1s

My project targets the latest version of Android (**`Android 8.1 API 27`**) and because of this, all versions should be 27 and above.

I think that this error is because of **`com.android.support:support-v4`** is **version 25.2.0** but when I searched my whole project, I was not able to find that `com.android.support:support-v4` or any file that is `25.2.0`.

Here are my gradle files if necessary:

**build.gradle (Project):**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {

        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'



        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
            maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        }



        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**build.gradle (module: app-base):**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.feature'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    baseFeature = true
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 3
        versionName "2.0.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags ""
            }
        }
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.1'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    //compile 'android-support-v7-appcompat:25.0.1'

    implementation 'com.github.HITGIF:TextFieldBoxes:1.3.8'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**build.gradle (module: appapk):**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26



    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "tr.k12.evrim.evrimnews.app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation project(':app-base')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

**build.gradle (module: instantapp):**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.instantapp'

android {
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':app-base')
}
```

Comment: run `gradlew appapk:dependencies` to show all your transitive dependencies.....that should highlight what's pulling in that version

Comment: @JohnO'Reilly this could be a stupid question, but how can I run that? Terminal? :(

Comment: yes, you'd run in that in terminal in root folder of your project (a little more background here - https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline.html)

Comment: @JohnO'Reilly Terminal output: https://gist.github.com/TurboProgramming/4e1ed10b622f650f469064ffa23a1527

Comment: @JohnO'Reilly any solutions?

Comment: did you try that command again after updating with `androidTestImplementation` and `implementation` ?

Comment: with your dependencies, the only issue I got was to update `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1'` to update o `27.0.2`, after which, gradle built just fine

Comment: @TWL I updated my com.android.support:appcompat-v7 file to 27.0.2 from 24.x.x But now, it wants me to change my com.android.support:appcompat-v4 file. But I'm not able to find that.

Comment: @TWL I tried running the command gave, and I've updated the gist file here you can see the new output there: https://gist.github.com/TurboProgramming/4e1ed10b622f650f469064ffa23a1527

Comment: com.github.HITGIF is still using the deprecated `compile`'s, remove it for now, then try the command again.

Comment: @TWL one minute please trying it now.

Comment: @TWL Still failing, I added the Command Line output to the same Gist page as a separate file: https://gist.github.com/TurboProgramming/4e1ed10b622f650f469064ffa23a1527

Comment: I recommend privately submitting your project to Google for a closer look https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=316045&template=1018787 Please mention this post and post a link back here too.

Comment: @TWL https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72994488

Answer (score 0):

With reference to [google issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72994488)  we were able to reproduce the issue in app with the same setup as in your `build.gradle` files.

The app can be ***successfully compiled*** when changing the `com.android.support:support-v4` dependency in base from **`implementation`** to **`api`** and ***updating*** `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1` to `27.0.2`.

The difference between **implementation** and **api** is that

**`implementation`** does not expose the dependency to other modules that depend on it, including libraries that need to be sync’d to the higher version (in this case, 25.x.x to 27).

While **`api`** dependencies will be exposed to all consumers of the library.